# yarn hardhat test -> Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: solidity, yarnpkg, hardhat

I'm new to yarn. I used npm to develop solidity programs before. When I tried to use yarn and `yarn hardhat test`. There's an error:

```
An unexpected error occurred:

SyntaxError: Error parsing /Users/xy/Desktop/program/test_test/node_modules/loupe/package.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at readPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:304:20)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:479:15)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xy/Desktop/program/test_test/node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/inspect.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14) {
  path: '/Users/xy/Desktop/program/test_test/node_modules/loupe/package.json'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

But I'm using the brand new hardhat demo, `yarn hard compile` is ok.
It's also ok if I use `npm`

And this is the demo script:

```
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

describe("Greeter", function () {
  it("Should return the new greeting once it's changed", async function () {
    const Greeter = await ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
    const greeter = await Greeter.deploy("Hello, world!");
    await greeter.deployed();

    expect(await greeter.greet()).to.equal("Hello, world!");

    const setGreetingTx = await greeter.setGreeting("Hola, mundo!");

    // wait until the transaction is mined
    await setGreetingTx.wait();

    expect(await greeter.greet()).to.equal("Hola, mundo!");
  });
});
```

It seems like a problem from `chai` because the problem disappeared when I removed the `expect` line.

Comment: run `npx hardhat clean` then compile it again and run your test cases and scirtps

Answer (score 0):

step 1 :

run `npx hardhat clean`

step 2 :

run what next it will get compile automatically